# How do I use TokenObtainPairView to don't return tokens for a class I created myself (inherited from AbstractUser)?

Tags: python, django, web, django-rest-framework, token

I've created a class that inherits from django's built-in user, which is successful when I want to create a new user by request. But when I access a token using the TokenObtainPairView view, it prompts
"{
"detail": "Can't find a valid user for the specified credentials"
}".

I have configured JWT in the setting:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10,

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=7),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=7)
}
```

In the meantime, my model is as follows:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    user_avatar = models.ImageField(null=False, blank=True, default='NONE',
                                    upload_to=user_avatar_path,
                                    validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'])])

    user_gender = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, default='NONE',
                                   max_length=10,
                                   choices=GENDER_CHOICE)

    user_created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user_updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'users'
        verbose_name = "user_table"
        ordering = ['user_created_at']

    def __str__(self):
        return f"User({self.id}->{self.username})"

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()
```

My url configuration is as follows:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view()),
    path('register/', RegisterView.as_view()),
    path('password/', PasswordView.as_view()),
    path('infomation/', UserView.as_view()),
    path('infomation/<int:pk>', UserDetailView.as_view()),

    path('token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view()),
    path('token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view()),
]
```

My Serializer is as follows:

```
class LoginTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    def validate(self, attrs):
        data = super().validate(attrs)
        data['username'] = self.user.username
        return data


class UserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(min_length=3, max_length=150)
    password = serializers.CharField(min_length=6, max_length=20, write_only=True)
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=False)

    user_avatar = serializers.ImageField(required=False)
    user_gender = serializers.ChoiceField(required=False, choices=GENDER_CHOICE)

    first_name = serializers.CharField(required=False, label='姓')
    last_name = serializers.CharField(required=False, label='名')

    is_staff = serializers.BooleanField(required=False, label='员工标识')
    is_active = serializers.BooleanField(required=False, label='冻结标识')
    is_superuser = serializers.BooleanField(required=False, label='管理员标识')

    last_login = serializers.DateTimeField(required=False, read_only=True)
    date_joined = serializers.DateTimeField(required=False, read_only=True)
    user_created_at = serializers.DateTimeField(required=False, read_only=True)
    user_update_at = serializers.DateTimeField(required=False, read_only=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.username = validated_data.get('username', instance.username)
        instance.password = validated_data.get('password', instance.password)
        instance.email = validated_data.get('email', instance.email)
        instance.user_avatar = validated_data.get('user_avatar', instance.user_avatar)
        instance.user_gender = validated_data.get('user_gender', instance.user_gender)
        instance.first_name = validated_data.get('first_name', instance.first_name)
        instance.last_name = validated_data.get('last_name', instance.last_name)
        instance.is_staff = validated_data.get('is_staff', instance.is_staff)
        instance.is_active = validated_data.get('is_active', instance.is_active)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

I tried to create a superuser in python utilizing the command, it is possible to access the token.
But the user created by my own post request is not accessible.

Particularly, I attempted to encrypt my password utilizing makepassword, but it doesn't seem to work. Additionally, I attempted to create the user utilizing create_user instead of create, but it still doesn't recognize the user I created myself.

Please help me with this if you can, it's very important to me and very much appreciated.